# CentOS - Duplicate yum-cron-hourly processes

Tags: centos7, cron, yum

yum-cron-hourly.conf is run hourly, the default, and I'm not sure its working correctly. There are multiple procs running.

```
root 17320 17306  0 16:01 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-cron /etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf 
root 17321 17306  0 16:01 ? 00:00:00 awk -v progname=/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron progname { ????   print progname ":\n" ????   progname=""; ??? } ??? { print; } 
root 22819 22795  0 17:01 ? 00:00:00 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-cron /etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf 
root 22820 22795  0 17:01 ? 00:00:00 awk -v progname=/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron progname { ????   print progname ":\n" ????   progname=""; ??? } ??? { print; }
```

Running `yum update` works fine and I see excluded packages ready to install.
I killed all procs and rebuilt the RPM-DB. The jobs eventually die-off and I've seen as many as 4 running at one time.

Does anyone know what's going on, or if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The extra procs eventually die off.
If anyone has any literature or knowlege of this process I would be interested in knowing.
I am curious.

Edit:
I believe this is related to the "random_sleep" setting.  I'm testing now and will update the post if anyone is interested.

Comment: Did you figure this out? ... I've got *way* more than 4 yum-cron procs sitting around on one of my boxes here.

Comment: I was not able to make any determinations as to the cause of these 'extra' processes.